# RxJava: PublishSubject acts synchronously

Tags: java, rx-java, publish-subscribe

I need a functionality that would allow to push asynchronously messages to my `PublishSubject` and to process them at a certain pace (actually one by one) via a `ConnectableObservable`. Unfortunately it seems that the call to `onNext` of the `PublishSubject` is not released until the underlying `Subscriber` processes the message.

It takes good few seconds to process each message and in debug mode I see that it executes before invocation of the method that pushes the message to PublishSubject is removed from stack - `"After push..."` always appear in console after internal logs inside the `Subscriber`...

So I have this RestEndpoint:

```
@PUT
@Path("{id}")
@TokenAuthenticated
public Response postResource(@PathParam(value="id") final String extId) {
    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Message metadata = processor.apply(extId);
                log.info("Before push...");
                dataImporter.pushData(metadata);
                log.info("After push...");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    return Response.ok("Request received successfully").build();

}
```

Here's the constructor of the DataImporter:

```
public DataImporter(final String configFile) {
        dataToImportSubject = PublishSubject.create();
        dataToImportObservable = dataToImportSubject.publish();
        dataToImportObservable.connect();
        dataToImportObservable
            .onBackpressureBuffer(1, new Action0() {

                @Override
                public void call() {
                    logger.debug("Buffer full...");
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Message>() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    logger.error("Error importing "+e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Message value) {
                    request(1);
                    importResult(configFile, value);
                }

                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    request(1);
                }
            });
    }
```

Then `pushData` of DataImporter is just pushing to `PublishSubject`'s `onNext` method..:

```
public void pushData(Message metadata) {
    dataToImportSubject.onNext(metadata);       
}
```

And here're the declaration of `PublishSubject` and `ConnectableObservable`:

```
public class DataImporter implements ImporterProxy{

    private final PublishSubject<Message> dataToImportSubject;
    private final ConnectableObservable<Message> dataToImportObservable;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PublishSubject`s emit to their consumers on the thread of the original `onXXX` call:

[JavaDocs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/PublishSubject.html)

> **Scheduler**:
>
> `PublishSubject` does not operate by default on a particular `Scheduler` and the `Observer`s get notified on the thread the respective `onXXX` methods were invoked.

You have to move the processing to some other thread with `observeOn` because the `observeOn` can move the `onXXX` calls to another thread.

`subscribeOn` does not have any practical effect on `Subject`s in general because it only affects the subscription thread, and won't modulate the subsequent `onXXX` calls to those subjects.

Answer (score 0):

RxJava, by default, is synchronous. You need to introduce operators into your observer chain to perform actions on other threads. When you read the documentation on each operator in `Observable`, you will see statements like "... does not operator on a particular scheduler" -- this indicates that data flows through that operator synchronously.

To get an observer chain to perform actions on other threads, you can use an operator like `subscribeOn()` with a scheduler to have operations performed on that scheduler. In your example, you likely will want to use `Schedulers.io()` to provide a background thread.

Comment: Hello @Bob I did put `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` when subscribing to my `ConnectableObservable`. You may see it in DataImporter's constructor.

Comment: Bob, `subscribeOn` has no practical effect on subjects. You need **the other** operator.

Comment: It worked with observeOn @akarnokd , thank you. If you wish, you can put your comment into an answer and I will happily accept it.